# Доступ к сайту если его заблокировал провайдер

Tags: хостинг

Есть некий веб ресурс, который принадлежит тебе, но его заблокировал провайдер в твоем городе. Если открывать через прокси с другим ip то сайт открывается, а напрямую никак. Как можно обойти это?

Comment: Вы хотите просто просматривать ресурс или работать с ним, с данными? Если просматривать - что-то у меня подозрения, что ответ в вопросе o_<

Comment: Ну если вы не можете договорится с провайдером, а ресурс ваш - перенесите его к другому провайдеру (хостеру)